# Creating a function for my code with datetime and timedelta

Tags: python-3.x, function, datetime, timedelta

I have finished my code and it works when I run it. However, I need to turn this into a function, that if I call the function and pass in any list of number, i can get the same results. This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
dateStr = 'user-input'
dateObj = datetime.strptime(dateStr, '%Y%m%d')
timeStep = timedelta(days=1)
dateObj2 = dateObj + timeStep
days15 = [dateObj + timeStep*i for i in range(15)]
print(days15)
```

------------------ output:

### datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0),..

I need to be able to pass in

```
date_str = "20170817"
results = days_15(date_str)
print(results)
```

And then get the same results. Any hints? or any help - Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a [`def`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#index-19) statement before your code to define the function, and rather than printing the result, [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#index-24) it:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def days_15(dateStr):
    dateObj = datetime.strptime(dateStr, '%Y%m%d')
    timeStep = timedelta(days=1)
    return [dateObj + timeStep*i for i in range(15)]

my_date_str = "20170817"
results = days_15(my_date_str)
print(results)
```

Output:

```
[
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 18, 0, 0), 
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 20, 0, 0), 
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 22, 0, 0), 
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 23, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 24, 0, 0), 
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 26, 0, 0), 
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 28, 0, 0), 
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 30, 0, 0), 
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 31, 0, 0)
]
```

Comment: thank you! I was just a bit confused on what to return at the end of the function.